# How can I fix Chrome to minimize into the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, google-chrome

Chrome, for the life of me won't minimize into the launcher. Every time I minimize it it goes away never to be seen again. This is a pain to have to deal with.

How can I fix it?

I was using the latest dev edition of Chrome.

Comment: Are you sure it is gone? What happens if you double-click the Chrome Launcher item?

Comment: It opens a new window of Chrome.

Comment: I can't confirm your findings with Chromium on 11.04 Unity. Maybe some plugin is the cause?

Comment: No plugins, this was a fresh install of Chrome.

Comment: Doesn't happen to me, but I suggest you turn on "use system title bars".

Answer (score 3):

Had this same problem after installing Chromium on 11.04, to fix it you just need to "Log Out..." and once you log back in its all fixed.

Eventually everybody will get this fixed because they will have to shut down or restart for other reasons but may never now what really fixed it.

Comment: This is the solution for me! So used to running Linux not needing to log out as much, so essentially the fix is to keep Chrome in the launcher, log out and log back in.. viola! Things are now working like they are supposed to

Answer (score 1):

This was hapening to me, and it was because I wasn't using the system title bars.  Preferences>>Personal Stuff>> toggle: "Use system title bar and borders"

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the experimental menu bar support in about:flags? I haven't tried it, but I saw the option there today.

Comment: Yup, still did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, and I'm not familiar with how the Unity Launcher works exactly, but I know I used to have this same problem in Windows 7. It stemmed from the application (chrome) not supporting the launcher properly - not the other way around - due to its tendency to have several processes running at once. There should be a workaround on one side of the fence (either with the launcher or chrome itself?)

It's also noteworthy that I've been testing all sorts of programs on the launcher, and as of yet, Chrome is the only one that does this.

Comment: Odd. Somehow it magically started working. I haven't done anything different, either, I just turned my laptop on for the first time today. I'll post updates if I figure out what just happened. All I've done so far is installed sun java 6, but that was for a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the restored window, and newly created windows, were opening off to the right of my visible display.
This persisted through a logoff.

click on the Chrome icon in the task bar, alt-f7 left arrow until the window appears on screen.

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-states.html.en