# Google Chrome unity icon does not restore after minimizing

Tags: 11.10, unity, google-chrome

After minimizing the Google Chrome window, clicking on the chrome icon in the unity sidebar doesn't restore the window. Additionally, the the icon seems to behave more like a launcher: no white indicators showing whether a window is open or not, and clicking on the icon just opens another instance of chrome. No other icon does this.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: have you installed the chrome by SOFTWARE CENTER or by downloading from the google.com ?

Comment: if you want to view them just press "super(windows)+w"

Comment: Software center only had Chromium, not Chrome, and I did download the .deb file from the official website.

and @VENKI, viewing the windows aren't really a problem. I just want the icon to do what it's supposed to.

Comment: have you tried to install from the .deb file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine here - the launcher icon for goggle-chrome launches & controls google-chrome plus the 2 quicklists options.

Maybe try resetting - Remove the icon from the launcher if pinned, then do a log out/in.

While you shouldn't need to,  try adding back to launcher this way - Browse in nautilus to /opt/google/chrome. Inside you'll see 'goggle-chrome.desktop'. Grab it with your cursor and DnD onto the unity launcher, then see if it works as intended.

This fixed the issue for me with  64 bit Ubuntu 12.04:  simply launching "chrome" from the dash didn't work, I had to use the nautilus method described above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Apparently, I neglected to look elsewhere on the site first for answers, and there is another question that deals with the same problem [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36975/how-can-i-fix-chrome-to-minimize-into-the-unity-launcher). Thank you for your time anyway!

Answer (score 1):

This happens if this setting in chrome is wrong, set
Preferences >> Personal Stuff >> toggle: "Use system title bar and borders"

[Google Chrome unity icon does not restore after minimizing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95067/google-chrome-unity-icon-does-not-restore-after-minimizing)

Answer (score -2):

I am really sorry to inform this that the chrome you installed from the software center was broken so please uninstall the chrome, and install it by downloading from [google](https://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?hl=en).

Comment: This is the exact site I downloaded from. I don't see how it can be broken.

Comment: have you got all back to normal

Comment: Look; **I did not install from the Ubuntu Software Center**. The site you linked me to is the same site I used to download the .deb package the first time. The icon still does not work after re-installing.

Comment: the above case is reverse is reverse sorry

Comment: the CHROMIUM and chrome are same do not get wrong idea by the name and then uninstall the one you installed and reinstall from the software center

Comment: Chromium and Chrome **ARE** different; Chromium is developed by the open source community, not Google. Chrome is derived from Chromium and is developed by Google.

Comment: Oh, look now the website's yelling at me to avoid extended discussions in comments. From now on, I will assume you do not know how to fix this. Please come up with a legitimate solution.

Comment: The latest chrome 17 is just not sitting well with unity bar. change the personal setting to use system title / menu doesn't cut it either. Already tried logging out, and even deleting the ~/.config/google-chrome won't help either. Guess I am going back to Firefox or Chromium.

Answer (score -3):

Disable all the extensions and close the browser. Try again and enable the extensions one by one.

That works for me.